# PostgreSQL: After restoring data, unable to use Views (permission denied)

Tags: postgresql, restore, permissions, postgresql-9.2, role

I'm attempting to get a PostgreSQL environment running locally.  I'm using 9.2.8, and have restored data from a backup made by the DBA of the production environment.

The restoration worked fine with 0 errors; however, in a couple of the Views there is a missing field that is in the production schema from which we restored our data.

As well, when attempting to do a simple select from the Views mentioned using the postgres role, I always get the following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation Map
********** Error **********
ERROR: permission denied for relation Map
SQL state: 42501
```

After doing some research (read: Googling), I tried GRANTing priveleges on the Schema, Views, and associated tables (in this case, the table 'Map') to avail.

Obviously, I'm a neophyte PostgreSQL user.  I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing.  But what could it be?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `in a couple of the Views there is a missing field`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot, I would start by looking at the output of `SELECT current_user;` and [`SHOW search_path;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777). Also, the output of `\dp termin` in psql.

My suspicion here is that you are stumbling over mixed case identifiers. The error message mentions a table

```
Map
```

Notice the capital letter **`M`**. Are you sure there is no mix-up with another table named `map` (lower case)?
[Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

(Or, in another schema coming earlier in the `search_path`?)

Comment: Thanks for the info, Erwin.  This was only one of many issues, but it was certainly case sensitivity that was at issue here!